# import MMWormhole on Cordova/WatchKit App

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, bridging-header

Im looking to import the MMWormhole module into my apple WatchKit app (in swift). Since I am building the app in swift, I need a bridging header bc the MMWormhole module was coded in objective C. My issue is that even if I have the below, I still receive issues about MMWormhole:

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h
#import "MMWormhole.h"

#endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
```

The error I receive is **No such module 'MMWormhole'**. The code that triggers this error is below:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import MMWormhole
import MMWormholeSession

class SyncController:WKInterfaceController {
    @IBOutlet var logo: WKInterfaceImage!
    @IBOutlet var loadingText: WKInterfaceLabel!
    let watchConnectivityListeningWormhole = MMWormholeSession.sharedListeningSession();
}
```

Please help me to understand what I may be doing wrong.

Also, I have made sure for my apple watch extension modify the Swift Compiler - General to include:

```
Install Object-C Compatibility Header=yes
Objective-C Bridging Header=<src_in_watchExtension_project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after hours of fiddling around, the solution was simple (which i thought it would be).

The answer is that Cordova will already install and setup your xCode compilers if you add the correct plugins (mine being *cordova-plugin-apple-watch*). When Compiled, you do not need to import MMWormhole...just make sure the bridging-header is set (like mine above).